# Пользователь не видит нового сообщения в чате

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, npm

Сделал чат, но у меня проблема в том, что новое сообщение не видно пользователю.

Пробовал сделать redirect, но так и не нашёл, как передать переменную. У меня чат передаёт GET id пользователя. Не знаю, как правильно сделать, чтобы новое сообщение видел пользователь

```
http://192.168.0.100/chat/chat.php?uid=6
```

Когда я ставлю redirect, то сообщение появляется, но мне хотелось бы написать код грамотнее: чтобы страница не тряслась от редиректа страницы.

Кроме того, не знаю, нужно в url GET передавать id того, с кем в чате говоришь, или лучше сразу делать POST'ом, так, чтобы не писать id в url для JavaScript запроса или jQuery?

Comment: Это о чём вообще вопрос?  Upd. перенёс из [другого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525920/7161) сюда начало вопроса.

Comment: "чтобы страница не тряслась от редиректа страницы" :D

Comment: Возможно автор сможет уточнить, что значит "Не тряслась от редиректа страницы" )

Comment: Проблема стоит в том чтоб пользователь не обновляя страницу сразу видел полученное сообщение в чате от другого пользователя

Comment: Как это сделать ?